# A question about Cayley-Chow forms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory

I'm reading some papers about $k$-stable theory and I have a question about Cayley-Chow forms. Maybe this question looks silly. Let X be a variety of $\mathbb{P}^N$ with dimension n and degree d. Since a Cayley-Chow form can be regarded as a polynominal of degree d in the pluker coordinate,how can this pulled back as a polynominal of degree (n+1)d in $\mathbf{C}[M_{(n+1)\times(N+1)}]$,where $M_{k\times l}$ denotes the space of all $k \times l$ matrices?